# How to give action on click of an image

Tags: iphone

I am developing an app in which what i want is when a user clicks on an image in an image view

An Action should be fired(like when a button is clicked).

I don't want button image. I just want an image view and action on it.

Kindly help.

Comment: easy way is set a transparent button on that image view and perform action...

Comment: @Maulik +1 for the method of champions!

Comment: Sorry..I don't want that..anyway thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment, if you want to know about image's index then you can do this by `tag` property of image view. Assign your image view's `tag` property as per your need and get the `tag` on **Touch event**.

For example :

Add `UITapGestureRecognizer`

```
ITapGestureRecognizer* tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                action:@selector(tap:)];
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

[self addGestureRecognizer:tap];

[tap release];
```

Use its delegate method : `- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event`

```
// called when touch is began or when user touches 
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject]; 

    int indexOfImageView = touch.view.tag;
}
```

Hope it helps you...

Answer (score 4):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected)];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    [singleTap release];


-(void)tapDetected{
    NSLog(@"single Tap on imageview");

}
```

Comment: Thanks..but if i have 5 images  and i wanna know about the index of image..Then how will i get the index of image..